# Variation of Problem

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

How would this problem ([Lebesgue Integral using Dominant Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2713760/432062)) change if it changed to

(1) lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \displaystyle\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} dx$

and

(2) lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \displaystyle\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2} dx$

Comment: Neither of these require the LDCT; both integrands have elementary anti-derivatives. For (1), the anti-dervative is $\frac{\log(1+n^2x^2)}{2n}$ and for (2), the anti-derative is $\arctan(nx)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one needs Arithmetic-Geometric inequality:
\begin{align*}
1+n^{2}x^{2}\geq 2nx,
\end{align*}
and for $x\ne 0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{nx}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}\leq\dfrac{nx}{2nx}=\dfrac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem goes through.

The second one need no big machine: 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{n}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}dx&=\int_{0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx=\tan^{-1}n\rightarrow\dfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: how did you go from $\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$ to $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: $y=nx$, so $x=0\rightarrow y=0$, $x=1\rightarrow y=n$, and $dy=ndx$.

Comment: are you using u-sub?

Comment: you are setting $u=n$?

Comment: Of course no, let $u=nx$, the $n$ here is fixed.

Comment: sorry i am very visual...so far I have set $u=nx$, then $du=ndx$. So the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{n} \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}dx = \int_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{1+u^2}du$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have written, just that I used the notation $y$ instead.

Comment: does this problem use dominant convergence or monotone?

Comment: In some sense, yes, by Monotone Convergence Theorem. Anyway, you can view it as an improper integral.